# Why is the shadow colored and not black?

Tags: texturing, light

I'm doing an animation of clock hands. The shadow of the object(Hand) looks like it has purple noise colour, which is also the colour of the hand. I understand that it's reflective due to the material. But the shadow should have been black rather than purple.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you understand that the material reflects the color of the hand, what solution would you like? Why not make the clock base material non-reflective instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the object and deselect the "diffuse" setting under Visibility

[image]

here with diffusion on:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Sanbaldo, I couldn't seem to get rid of the colour. 

Kind regards.